# How to control flow of multiple Rss Files

Tags: java-me, lwuit, nokia, midp

I developed RssFeed Application using LWUIT j2me(java) for 2 xml files, now I want to show those 2 xml files on LWUIT Tabs.

That means, when my application runs, default tab will be displayed (on that tab my first Rss xml file Titles should be displayed), and when the user click on tab2 my second Rss xml titles should be displayed.

I am able to display the same titles of one rss files on both the tabs, how to control my flow to achieve my task?

Here my code:

```
public class XMLMidlet extends MIDlet implements ActionListener {

    public XMLMidlet() {
        Display.init(this);
        news = new Vector();
        m_backCommand = new Command("Back");

        cmdExit = new Command("EXIT");
        cmdDetails = new Command("Details");
    }

    public void startApp() {
    //RssFeed URL's     
   String urls[] = {"http://topnews-23.rss",
      "http://topstory-12.rss"};

  for(int i=0;i<urls.length;i++){
        ParseThread myThread = new ParseThread(this,urls[i]);
        //this will start the second thread
        myThread.getXMLFeed(urls[i]);
            }
    }

     //method called by the parsing thread

    public void addNews(News newsItem,String url) {
        try{
        news.addElement(newsItem);
        form1 = new Form();

        myNewsList = new List(newsVector);
        newsList    =new List(newsVector);
        myNewsList.setRenderer(new NewsListCellRenderer());
        newsList.setRenderer(new NewsListCellRenderer());

        tabs=new Tabs(Component.TOP);

        tabs.addTab("TopNews", myNewsList);

        tabs.addTab("Topstory",newsList);

        form1.addComponent(tabs);
        form1.show();
  }

        catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();     
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move below code

```
myNewsList = new List(newsVector);
newsList    =new List(newsVector);
myNewsList.setRenderer(new NewsListCellRenderer());
newsList.setRenderer(new NewsListCellRenderer());
tabs=new Tabs(Component.TOP);
form1 = new Form();
tabs=new Tabs(Component.TOP);
tabs.addTab("TopNews", myNewsList);
tabs.addTab("Topstory",newsList);
```

from `addNews` method to constructor `XMLMidlet`. `addNews` method should use `url` parameter to differ for which list the `newsItem` is directed.

**Update**

Below is how I think you should implement `addNews` method:

```
public void addNews(News newsItem, String url) { 
  if (url.endsWith("topnews-20.rss")) {
    myNewsList.addElement(newsItem);
  } else if (url.endsWith("topstory-25.rss")) {
    newsList.addElement(newsItem);
  }
}
```

`serRenderer` does not need to be called from `addNews` and `form1.show()` should be moved to `startApp`.